# Printing a particular value from an array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I print the value of a Fibonacci function for any particular index, say n, where n is the provided argument value?

```
1 import java.util.Arrays;
2 
3 public class Fibonacci {
4
5 public static void main(String[] args) {
6   int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
7   if(n<3){
8       return;
9   }else{
10      int[] f = new int[n];
11      f[0] = 1;
12      f[1] = 1;
13      int i= 0;
14      for(i=2; i<f.length; i++){
15          f[i]= f[i-1]+ f[i-2];
16      }
17      System.out.println(f[i]);
18  }
19  
20 }
21
22 }
```

Comment: I think your Fibonacci function is incorrect. This should a `recursive` function.

Comment: Isn't this already doing the same thing? Or explain more what exactly you needc

Comment: +hamed The fibonacci function seems right because when I instead use System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f)) it works fine !!

Comment: Mr. 777 compiler gives error on line 17 i.e. on the System.out.println( f[i] )

Comment: @Abi What is the compiler error?

Comment: @Mr.777 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at Fibonacci.main(Fibonacci.java:17)

Comment: So, how is it a compiler error? It's a runtime error. which means that you are trying to access out of bound index. Please debug your code and if you would always want to print the last value then do something like:

System.out.println(f[f.length-1] otherwise, you need to get the index which is inbound

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question.  So what is your problem? You do not know how to get command line argument? or you do not know how to convert command line argument to an integer?

Comment: Thank you @Mr.777 I got it..  it works yay !!

Comment: @Adrian I guess I know both. The first is : using Run configuration in eclipse and second : by using Integer.parseInt , right? The real doubt was what Mr. 777 pointed out i.e. using inbound index.

Comment: ic, then please refer to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is basically fine, but I tweaked a few things in my response:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    if (n < 0) {
        System.out.println("Cannot computer Fib() of a negative number.");
        return(0);
    } else if (n < 3) {
       System.out.println("Fib[" + n + "] = 1");
    } else {
        int[] f = new int[n];
        f[0] = 1;
        f[1] = 1;
        for(int i=2; i < f.length; ++i) {
            f[i] = f[i-1]+ f[i-2];
        }
        System.out.println("Fib[" + n + "] = " + f[n - 1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have, I believe, is `System.out.println(f[i]);`

At this spot, `i` will be equals to length of `f[]`.  If you use `i` as index, it will be out of bound.

If you are going to print the last value, it should be `System.out.println(f[i-1]);`

Answer (score 1):

You are printing `f[i]` which will give you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since at that time value of `i` crosses the boundary of array `f`.

A simple workaround would be to print array by taking a separate variable like this :

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
if(n<3){
    return;
}else{
    int[] f = new int[n];
    f[0] = 1;
    f[1] = 1;
    int i= 0;
    for(i=2; i<f.length; i++){
        f[i]= f[i-1]+ f[i-2];
     }

     for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
     System.out.println(f[j]);
    }
}
```

If you want to print any particular index then you can make one boundary check before printing:

```
int index=5;
if(index<f.length){
    System.out.println(f[index]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what have you done in the second "for-loop"? Sorry, I didn't get that :(

Comment: in second loop I am just printing all values of array.
But if you want to print any particular value then you can add one boundary check.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's better to have Fibonachi in the recursive way:

```
public int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
       return n;
    }
    else {
       return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
    }
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: This is **not** preferable to a non-recursive solution, as the recursive solution will explode for higher values of n.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen for telling the difference I never knew that :)

Comment: To illustrate the point @TimBiegeleisen is making, it will take 500 addition operations to calculate fib(501) the iterative way and over 10^100 additions to do it the recursive way.  That's more additions than there are atoms in the observable universe.